# Jquery issue multiple input file and array

Tags: jquery, arrays, input

Hi everybody i'm having an issue with an input file multiple.
I'd like to validate my files before uploading them on server so i am trying to build an array of "good files" and clone the original input with those good values ... But it isn't working ... My array is empty and no files are submitted ... As i'm quite noob in jquery i can't solve this issue alone :/

Here's the html :

```
<input id="creativeSelect" name="creativeSelect[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
<div id="alert"></div>
<table id="dvPreview"></table>
```

And the jquery part :

```
if (typeof selectedCreative == "undefined" || !(selectedCreative instanceof Array)) { selectedCreative = []; }
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
var files = evt.target.files; 
var filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(files);

for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

var goUpload = true;

if (!f.name.match(/(?:gif|jpg|png|bmp)$/)) {
$('<p class="bg-danger">'+ f.name +' must be an image file only</p>').appendTo('#alert').delay(5000).queue(function() { $(this).remove(); });

        goUpload = false;
    }
    if (f.size > 307200) { // 300k
        $('<p class="bg-danger">'+ f.name +' is too big, max size allowed is 300kb</p>').appendTo('#alert').delay(5000).queue(function() { $(this).remove(); });

        goUpload = false;
    }
    if (goUpload) {   

    var myobject = filesArr[i];
    selectedCreative.push(myobject); 

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
        return function (e) {
            // Render thumbnail.
            var name = theFile.name;
            var size = Math.floor(theFile.size/1024);
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            var imgsrc = e.target.result;
            img.src = imgsrc;
            var w = img.width;
            var h = img.height;
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            tr.innerHTML = ['<td><img src="', imgsrc, '" title="', escape(name), '"/></td><td>', escape(name), '</td><td>', escape(w), ' x ', escape(h), '</td><td>', escape(size), 'ko </td>'].join('');
            document.getElementById('dvPreview').insertBefore(tr, null);
        };
    })(f);

    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}

        var input = $('#creativeSelect');
        input.replaceWith(input.val('').clone(true));
        input.val(selectedCreative);

}

document.getElementById('creativeSelect').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

I am trying to filters the files, if they match my criterias, the goUpload loop is supposed to store them into the selectedCreative array  and at the end of the file i try to clone the select and fill it with the selectedCreative array ...

Sorry for my poor english :)